# Sort based on the service time of stores

Tags: elasticsearch

My project contains some stores with their working time and I index them in `ElasticSearch`. Now there are some scenarios in my product:

1. Whenever the client requests for the stores which are available now, I use the following range filter:

   ```
   bool: {
          must: [
                 { range: {startTime: { lte: now}} },
                 { range: {endTime: { gte: now}} }
                ]
   }
   ```

   Let's call the result Online stores.
2. When the client requests for all stores, I have to give them all the documents, but I have to sort them, first online stores and then other stores.

I can do that by two queries, one for online and another one for offline store but I want to do that once. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) as an "optional" clause:

> If the `bool` query is in a query context and has a `must` or `filter`
>   clause then a document will match the bool query even if none of the
>   `should` queries match. In this case these clauses are only used to
>   influence the score.
>
> The bool query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score
>   from each matching must or should clause will be added together to
>   provide the final _score for each document.

The query might look like this:

```
POST my-should/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "should": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "startTime": {
                  "lte": "2018-06-24T16:39:59"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "endTime": {
                  "gte": "2018-06-22T16:39:59"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "_name": "Online"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `match` part of this `bool` query will define which documents will match, and the `should` part will boost those that also match additional criteria.

Note that here we used [Named Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) to highlight that the "Online" part of the query was matched to a document. The response could look like this:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my-should",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "BKgZLWQBERN2JBe1CQ5t",
    "_score": 3,
    "_source": {
      "startTime": "2018-06-23T16:39:59",
      "endTime": "2018-06-23T16:39:59"
    },
    "matched_queries": [
      "Online"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-should",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "BagaLWQBERN2JBe12A7y",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "startTime": "2018-06-20T16:39:59",
      "endTime": "2018-06-21T16:39:59"
    }
  }
]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's really helpful but the problem is that "matched_queries" won't appear in the result.

Comment: @SamanGholami If `matched_queries` do not appear, it means none of the queries with names matched. Pls check that query in isolation (only that query) and see if it returns a result.